# Not touching timestamps for certain field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, filtering

I have several models with timestamps and `active` fields and several parts in my code where I update them.
I want to be able to update the model and only touch timestamps when the updated model changes more than the acttive field.
So my code is

```
 const leaveUntouched=["active"=>true]
 ...   
 $instance = $model::find($data["id"]);
 $changed = array_diff_assoc($data,$instance->toArray());
 $needTimestampTouch = array_diff_key($changed,self::leaveUntouched);
 if (empty($needTimestampTouch))
   $instance->timestamps = false;
 $instance->fill($data);
 $instance->save();
```

It would be much cleaner, if I could define this in the BaseModel itself.
Should I extend the Fill Method of Eloquent/Model in my Baseclass? And how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

I put this in my Baseclass and it works:

```
protected $preventTouch=['active'];

public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $needsUpdate=array_diff(
        array_keys($this->getDirty()),
        $this->preventTouch
    );
    $this->timestamps = count($needsUpdate) > 0;
    parent::save($options);
}
```